# Zendframework 3- Doctrine : can't get entityManager in Application/Module

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I use Zendframework 3 with Doctrine 2.2
I'm writing a little tool that use 2 modules:

Users module that use Doctrine/EntityManager for access and session data.

Application module that use Doctrine/EntityManager for retrieving info from entitues and various repository.

The mistery is: why in Users module I can retrieve

> 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'

in every factories but in Application module don't?

I have read my code 1000 time, no error in log, every factory is correctly mapped.

The serviceManager is ok because other services are correctly getted.

This is the"Application" module.config.php

[MODULE:CONFIG:PHP](https://pastebin.com/8UL7WZ4W)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your `config/modules.config.php`?

Comment: Just updated with source code :-D

Comment: Did you notice that on line 185 your config has `#*/` behind the closing bracket? Is that maybe your problem?

Comment: No, the closing bracket is commented by #, removing nothing change.